# How to Freeze the Header on an ASPX page

Tags: application-pages, aspx, header

I have an aspx file that pulls data from 3 different lists and compiles them. The script outputs data into a table with a header.

There is a lot of information so when a user scrolls down, they loose the header and sometimes will have to scroll up to see what column is the data associated with.

I have seen articles on how to freeze the header in lists. However, how can I freeze a header in an aspx file?

Any links or suggestions would be helpful. Someone told me that it was impossible but wanted to at least check before giving up.

Comment: Are you want fixed header for table? And table is generated using HTML?

Comment: See these two example: 
http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/jmosbech/stFcx/